# How to show data after fetching

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm fetching data from Mongodb but the data is showing me undefined, when I try it in Postman it's working but in the app it's not.

API Side **`The Router`**:

```
router.get("/:shopName", async (req, res) => {
    const shopIdOrName = req.params.shopName;
    var shop;
    try {
       // check if its valid id, else its name
       if(mongoose.isValidObjectId(shopIdOrName)){
          shop = await Shop.findById(shopIdOrName )
       } else {
          shop = await Shop.findOne({ shopName: shopIdOrName });
       }
       const { updatedAt, ...others } = shop._doc;
       res.status(200).json(others);
     } catch (err) {
       res.status(500).json("Shop not found!");
     }
   });
```

Client Side **`ShopPage.jsx:`**

```
  const [shop, setShop] = useState({});
  const shopName = useParams().shopName;

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchShop = async () => {
      const res = await axios.get(`/shops?shopName=${shopName}`);
      setShop(res.data);
    };
    fetchShop();
  }, [shopName]);

return (
                <Box>
                  <Typography
                      className=""
                      mt="5px"
                      variant="h5"
                      fontWeight="medium"
                      align="left"
                      style={{ color: "black" }}>
                      {capitalizeFirstLetter(`${shop.shopName} `)} 
                  </Typography>
                </Box>
);
```

In my Client Side **`App.js`** I'm using this route:

```
<Route path="/:shopName" element={<ShopPage />}>
</Route>
```

It supposed to show me the shop name, but instead it showing me "undefined", I don't know what i'm missing here.

Comment: you can console.log(res.data) to see what does it contain.

Comment: at the first time render, your shop doesn't contain shopName because it is only {}, so maybe you can add condition for to render you component { shop?.shopName &&  <Box>...</Box>}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see that you are accepting the route on Backend is '/:shopname'
but from the frontend you are sending it like  `/shops?shopName=${shopName}` which is a query string .
you should send it like

```
axios.get(`${shopName`)
```

or if your route in backend is bound with path `/shop/shopname` then you should send the request from frontend like this:

```
axios.get(`/shop/${shopName`)
```